# Diagrammatic expansion of an operator insertion in path integral for Trace Anomaly calculation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, quantum-anomalies, trace

Starting with a scale invariant classical field theory, we can prove that the energy-momentum tensor will be traceless.

\begin{equation}
\Theta^\mu_{\ \mu }=0
\end{equation}

In the context of the trace anomaly it is usual to treat the insertion of the trace of the energy-momentum tensor perturbatively to find out it it has a loop correction

\begin{equation}
\langle \hat{\Theta}^\mu_{\ \mu }\rangle=\int\mathcal{D}\phi \ \Theta^\mu_{\ \mu }\  e^{-S_E}
\end{equation}

My first question is: What exactly is an "insertion"? Or in other words, what exactly are we calculating on the left hand side? is it just $\langle 0|\Theta^\mu_{\ \mu }|0\rangle$ or does it have in and out states and the energy-momentum tensor works like a propagator of some sort?

I'm reading chapter 19 of Peskin and this questions arose in section 19.5 and, specifically, on figure 19.10

[image]

On that chapter he's dealing with a trace of the form

\begin{equation}
\Theta^\mu_{\ \mu }=(1-d)i\bar{\psi}\not{D}\psi+(\frac{d}{4}-1)F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}
\end{equation}

which makes me think that the insertion of the energy-momentum tensor could couple to two photons, two fermions or two fermions and a photon (because of the covariant derivative). Seeing at figure 9.10 I don't understand why does he have external photon legs, why doesn't he have external fermionic legs, or why is he using the insertion like that in general.

Comment: If I remember correctly P&S use the background field method in this example. They integrate out the fluctuating field. The ``photon'' lines then correspond to the background field.

Comment: Already answered here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/474249/relation-between-the-trace-anomaly-and-the-energy-momentum-tensor-being-off-shel/478333#478333